# Repeat an image without using bulit function for repeat image in OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, matrix-multiplication

Basically here if we define a function i.e. repeat_image that takes three arguments in that function a matrix image and two integers nx, ny, and return a new image that is nx*ny times bigger, by repeating the image nx*ny times.
So if initial image was 640*480, repeat_image( img, 2, 2 ) will return an image of size 1280*960.
The arguments are:
- an matrix image (type Mat)
- an integer nx, the number of times the matrix should be repeated along the horizontal axis
- an integer ny, the number of times the matrix should be repeated along the vertical axis

Comment: you should add the code you tried and why it doesn't work. Consider my other answer as a _Welcome to SO gift_, but you should put some effort into the code, even more because this smells like an homework.

Comment: you can start looking at `copyTo` function. Once you create a destination matrix big enough, you just need to copy the source matrix in the correct place.

Comment: This is a relatively easy exercise. Start with your course notes and try it yourself. You will find it not that difficult at all.

Comment: Yes i have tried.....and yes i will surely put the code as well here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Mat image_repeat(Mat &img, int nx, int ny) 

{


    Mat img_repeat(Size(nx * img.cols, ny * img.rows), CV_8UC3);
    int y = 0, x = 0;
    while (y < ny)
     { //0<3
        while (x < nx)
          { //0<2
            for (int row = 0; row < img.rows; row++) 
              {
                for (int col = 0; col < img.cols; col++)
                  {
                    img_repeat.at<Vec3b>(Point(col + (img.cols * x), row + (img.rows * y))) =img.at<Vec3b>(Point(col, row));
                    }
              }
            x++;
        }
        x = 0;
        y++;
    }

    cout << "Image Repeat Done." << endl;

    return img_repeat;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? If it doesn't, and it's just the code that you've tried and want to improve, then it should not be posted as an answer; it should be edited into your original question. Please take the time to learn how things work on Stackoverflow. You can take the [tour] and review [ask].

Comment: Oh actually i am new on stackoverflow. This is what i did and got the correct answer so i wanted to post it as my answer :)

Comment: Very good. I suggest you add a statement at the beginning of the answer saying that you have found the solution to your problem, and perhaps describing what you've done, rather than simply dumping code. I realize that you are new here, which is why I suggested that you visit the two links I gave above.

Answer (score 1):

You can repeat an image:

- creating the destination image of the correct size
- copying the source image with `cv::copyTo` in the correct ROI

Code:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
using namespace cv;

Mat image_repeat(const Mat& src, int nx, int ny)
{
    Mat dst(src.rows * ny, src.cols * nx, src.type());

    for (int iy = 0; iy < ny; ++iy)
    {
        for (int ix = 0; ix < nx; ++ix)
        {
            Rect roi(src.cols * ix, src.rows * iy, src.cols, src.rows);
            src.copyTo(dst(roi));
        }
    }
    return dst;
}


int main()
{
    Mat3b img = imread("path_to_image");

    Mat3b res = image_repeat(img, 4, 3);

    imshow("img", img);
    imshow("res", res);
    waitKey();

    return 0;
}
```

**NOTES**

- this method works for any kind of input image